# MySQL: Does the referenced column need to be primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I execute following SQL code to create database and tables, I got error message: `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`. If I make `test.book.storeID` to be primary key, the code works. Does the referenced column need to be primary key?

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `test` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`book` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `storeID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `storeID_UNIQUE` (`storeID` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`shoppingCartItem` (
  `userID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bookID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `storeID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`, `bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_idx` (`bookID` ASC, `storeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`bookID` , `storeID`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`book` (`ID` , `storeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key reference should be to a primary key, although it can also be to a unique key.  MySQL allows foreign key relationships to any indexed column, but I wouldn't recommend that.

So, the foreign key reference should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`bookID`) REFERENCES `test`.`book` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I do question why you have `storeid` in both tables.  If they need to be the same, then it should only be in one table and you can look it up using the key.

Comment: UNIQUE INDEX already exists, but still fail to add foreign key constraint. What's the reason?

Comment: @AlpacaMan . . . You have two keys, not a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

See if the answer in this question helps [does foreign key always reference to a unique key in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706073/does-foreign-key-always-reference-to-a-unique-key-in-another-table), basically it needs to be unique, not primary.