# Reference the name instead of the id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

guys I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve yet, I haven't found anything on the web, I need to reference in my table the field nome_mulher instead of the field id of the table 'women' within my other table 'aggressors' or if it is possible to reference these two fields within the 'aggressors' table.

table agressors

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('agressors', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('mulher_id');
        $table->foreign('mulher_id')->references('id')->on('mulhers');
        $table->string('nome')->nullable();
        $table->string('idade')->nullable();
        $table->string('vinculo')->nullable();
        $table->string('escolaridade')->nullable();
        $table->string('rua_agressor')->nullable();
        $table->string('bairro_agressor')->nullable();
        $table->string('numero_agressor')->nullable();
        $table->string('profissao')->nullable();
        $table->string('tipo_de_agressão')->nullable();
        $table->string('primeira_agressao')->nullable();
        $table->string('vezes_de_agressao')->nullable();
        $table->string('boletim_de_ocorrencia')->nullable();
        $table->string('numero_boletim')->nullable();
        $table->string('dependencia_quimica_agressor')->nullable();
        $table->string('qual_quimico_agressor')->nullable();
        $table->string('passagem_prisional_agressor')->nullable();
        $table->string('tempo')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

table mulhers

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('mulhers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nome_mulher')->nullable();
        $table->string('nome_social')->nullable();
        $table->string('primeiro_registro')->nullable();
        $table->string('data_de_registro')->nullable();
        $table->string('nome1')->notnullable()->change();
        $table->date('data_de_nascimento')->nullable();
        $table->string('cpf')->nullable();
        $table->string('pai')->nullable();
        $table->string('mae')->nullable();
        $table->string('etnia')->nullable();
        $table->string('religiao')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('possui_bolsa_familia')->nullable();
        $table->string('celular')->nullable();
        $table->string('tel_fixo')->nullable();
        $table->string('beneficio_social')->nullable();
        $table->string('renda')->nullable();
        $table->string('pensao_alimenticia')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('carteira_de_trabalho')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('dependente_quimico')->nullable();
        $table->string('qual_quimico')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('medicacao')->nullable();
        $table->string('qual_medicacao')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('pessoa_com_deficiencia_fisica')->nullable();
        $table->string('qual_deficiencia_fisica')->nullable();
        $table->string('tipo_cancer')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('possui_cancer')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('trans_mental')->nullable();
        $table->string('qual_trans_mental')->nullable();
        $table->string('hiv')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('possui_passagem')->nullable();
        $table->string('tempo_de_passagem')->nullable();
        $table->string('rua')->nullable();
        $table->string('numero')->nullable();
        $table->string('bairro')->nullable();
        $table->string('situacao_moradia')->nullable();
        $table->string('estado_civil')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('possui_filhos')->nullable();
        $table->string('quantos_filhos')->nullable();
        $table->string('escolaridade')->nullable();
        $table->string('profissao')->nullable();
        $table->string('genero')->nullable();
        $table->string('cidade_da_mulher')->nullable();
        $table->string('id_genero')->nullable();
        $table->string('sexualidade')->nullable();
        $table->string('sexo')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('gestante')->nullable();
        $table->string('id_gestante')->nullabel();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to migrate `mulhers` before `agressors`

Comment: Also, if these are highly related tables, you can put both ```Schema::create``` statements in one migration ```up()``` method.

Comment: What's your question about this? What do you mean by "reference"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for every help, i appreciate that, i tring this solutions

Answer (score 0):

If a foreign key is not referencing a primary key on the parent table it must reference a unique key. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706073/does-foreign-key-always-reference-to-a-unique-key-in-another-table)

That is why you need to change in your `mulhers` table:

```
$table->string('nome_mulher')->nullable()->unique();
```

In your `agressors` table change the lines to:

```
$table->string('nome_mulher');
$table->foreign('nome_mulher')->references('nome_mulher')->on('mulhers');
```

After that, migrate `mulhers` table first and then `agressors` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, i tring this solution